# Why is T-SQL WHERE NOT IN Returning one of the filtered elements

Tags: t-sql

In my below query I among others filter on specific values with NOT IN, which for most part works like it should, but one of the filtered values (not the others) still returns in the view, and I cannot figure out why this is happening .. the value that is returned is '76751219' .. Can anyone help me figure out why?

**The query:**

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @json = (SELECT PHONE_DATA FROM EFP_JSON WHERE ID = 1)
SELECT PhoneNumber
FROM EFP_PhoneNumberSeries
WHERE REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') NOT IN (
SELECT PhoneNumbers.Number
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (   
Localnumber VARCHAR(50) '$.Localnumber',
Name VARCHAR(50) '$.Name',
Email VARCHAR(50) '$.Email',
PhoneNumbers nvarchar(max) '$.PhoneNumbers' AS JSON,
Phones nvarchar(max) '$.Phones' AS JSON       
) as UserInfo
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(PhoneNumbers)
WITH(
Number nvarchar(100) '$.Number',
LineName nvarchar(100) '$.LineName',
GotoLocalNumber nvarchar(100) '$.GotoLocalNumber',
BelongsTo nvarchar(100) '$.BelongsTo'
)  as PhoneNumbers
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Phones)
WITH(
description nvarchar(100) '$.description'
) as description
) AND REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '')  LIKE '767512%' OR REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') LIKE '767520%'
AND LTRIM(REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '')) NOT IN ('76752000','76752005','76752006','76752007','76752008','76752010','76752011','76752012','76751219','76751221','76752022','76752058','76752060','76752063','76752097','76752098');
```

Comment: PhoneNumberSeries' smells of bad DB design...

Comment: Almost certainly bad data; can you post sample data.

Comment: @Mitch .. PhoneNumberSeries contains contains phone numbers that are formatet like "XX XX XX XX".

Comment: I see `AND` and `OR` in the `WHERE` clause. Perhaps you are missing some parenthesis there

Comment: Thank you @Squirrel .. I was missing  parenthesis in the last part, and had to swap the last parts round so it became :
`AND REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') NOT IN ('76752000','76752005','76752006','76752007','76752008','76752010','76752011','76752012','76751219','76751221','76752022','76752058','76752060','76752063','76752097','76752098')
AND (REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '')  LIKE '767512%' OR REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') LIKE '767520%');`
Feel  free to post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

76751219 is being returned because it matches the `REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '')  LIKE '767512%'` criteria regardless of the `NOT IN` filter.

To resolve this, you need to fix the parenthesis in the last few lines as you appear to be missing some. Based on what you've said, I think those lines should read

```
AND ( -- add this round opening bracket
    REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '')  LIKE '767512%'
    OR REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '') LIKE '767520%'
) -- add this round closing bracket
AND LTRIM(REPLACE(PhoneNumber, ' ', '')) NOT IN ('76752000','76752005','76752006','76752007','76752008','76752010','76752011','76752012','76751219','76751221','76752022','76752058','76752060','76752063','76752097','76752098');
```

but you should review this yourself to make sure it meets your requirements for the AND & OR logic.